# How to adapt Currency and Date formatting from US to India computers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file that contains dates and currencies.

The dates are currently formatted as:

> [$-en-US]m/d/yy

The date formatting works currently for the US but not India:

`US enters 4/6/20 --> 4/6/20, India Enters 4/6/20 --> 6/4/20.`

Is it possible to have the data entered on the India computer entered in the same way as the US (4/6/20 --> 4/6/20)?

The currencies are currently formatted as:

> [$$-en-US]#,##0.00

On the US computer, this works. On the India computer, the $ forces the text to be a string. How can I get this to be US currency values on both computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Excel date formats adjust to the computer's regional settings. These date formats are marked with an asterisk and are showing at the top of the list of date formats in the formatting dialog Number tab.

In the screenshot below, the Locale is New Zealand and the top date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`. If this file is opened on a computer with US settings, the date will appear as `mm/dd/yyyy`. If the file is opened on a computer with German settings, the date will appear as `dd.mm.yyyy`.

So, use only date formats with the asterisk if you need dates to adjust formatting across different regional settings and allow date entry in your familiar format.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.